# How to get image url in magento 2 on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, product-images

How to get image url in magento 2 on checkout page custom phtml file.

I created the custom phtml. I need to get the product image in that phtml file

Comment: cart product image ??

Comment: Impossible to know, without knowing what block your custom.phtml is using. Is the product / item loaded?